# How to infer types using array entries

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
type A2 = {
    label: 'name';
    render: (v: string) => any;
  } | {
    label: 'age';
    render: (v: number) => any;
  } | {
    label: ['name'];
    render: (v: string) => any;
  } | {
    label: ['age'];
    render: (v: number) => any;
  }

  const a1: A2 = {
    label: 'age',
    render: (v) => v,
  }

  const a2: A2 = {
    label: ['name'],
    render: (v) => v,
  }
```

In a1, render's 'v' is infered as 'number' correctly.But in a2, it's 'any'.I want to know what's the diffrence and why. Is it a bug for Typescript?

Comment: Or it caused by the difference between Primitive values and Objects?

Comment: Yeah, you can't discriminate the union over object types

Comment: It's because the first two are discriminated unions, The discriminant must be a primitive type. In the absence of that you won't get contextual typing if more than one signature ca be the type for the function :https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTFAvFA3gKClAThAdgEwiwC4oAKAN1IGdgsBLXAcwEokA+KAQ1xAG40AXygAfVBmx5CJclSi4ArgFsARkTaJOPfkLR6AxgHtctbnFLwk4zDgJFSlDZwoAaIUA

Comment: Like @RobertoZvjerković already stated, your solution should be closer to this kind of implementation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTFAvFA3gKCpqAbAhgIwmwC4oByAO1wFsIyoAfc3AczoG4MsAnCCgEwjdSACgBupAM7BuASwotGUCgFdqhbgEokAPigqKAawoB7AO4VOmAL5L0WHASKkA2pRp0lZVnQC6Vnj5BYShxKRl5RSZVdSFtRD0DY3NLLms0LgBjEwppKFwARlJ4JFQuTDxCEmY2MgAacqheASFRMXi9MQabDMxs3OB8uGKEZHssSucoNypaMl9uwJaQ8Q6oLrSgA

Comment: This is how discriminated unions are implemented in [rescript](https://rescript-lang.org/try?code=C4TwDgpgBAtiBKEDOYD2A7J0C8AoKUAPlAJrIAUAlusAJT5FQByqVN9BxACgE4TCgAsgFcAxgAs2dXLgA2-KCGRRspCgEZ684FHSoVzVgAYtCmAENhAIxy9+QsZIBM9IA). As you might have noticed they are using just `tag` property and primitive value

Comment: [Here](https://fable.io/repl/#?code=C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwLwDElID4CECGATnvgF4BQ5ANhMFAGZYZbW1QBGRqBhrdnpbmSA&html=DwCwLgtgNgfAUHUBTAhgE3gAk8CSwqbhgAOAtEgI4CuAlgG4C8A5AMID2AdmEt2QCoBPEkmaYAxlx7cWPAB5gA9OGgBuCSBQAnAM75G1MADMyADmZYcO8VtokwmHVvGMARMRI6AXIsXVOJADWAOYAdJIQigACAO5IAEYRJFy8YDqK4tQ6YOwQFFBIeNw6UQCMoQBMoQAMGVk5eUgFRWmhELScoQBWOq4wwIrWtvaWwEN2Dk4u7mCk3r7+QWER0XGJucmcqek6mmiCaLlloeUAzIN7B7ltHd29-YM2E-ADIKgYCMDx7PsSUCg6HRuFAkciSbgoDpILR9ODYbC4QRkeKGHKcTD-eJNNzsdh9AYQJEo2ZcF6Kb77eCIZSQWBwIA&css=Q) you can check how Fable works

Answer (score -1):

Just posting this as an answer as suggested by Samuli Hakoniemi in the comments to make it easier for future viewers.

You need to use a union inside the array definition:

```
type A2 = {
    label: 'name' | 'age';
    render: (v: string | number) => unknown;
  } | {
    label: ['name' | 'age'];
    render: (v: string | number) => unknown;
  }

  const a1: A2 = {
    label: 'age',
    render: (v) => v,
  }

  const a2: A2 = {
    label: ['name'],
    render: (v) => v,
  }
```

[Typescript Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTFAvFA3gKCpqAbAhgIwmwC4oByAO1wFsIyoAfc3AczoG4MsAnCCgEwjdSACgBupAM7BuASwotGUCgFdqhbgEokAPigqKAawoB7AO4VOmAL5L0WHASKkA2pRp0lZVnQC6Vnj5BYShxKRl5RSZVdSFtRD0DY3NLLms0LgBjEwppKFwARlJ4JFQuTDxCEmY2MgAacqheASFRMXi9MQabDMxs3OB8uGKEZHssSucoNypaMl9uwJaQ8Q6oLrSgA)